# Parsing JSON Single Value Array becomes string

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsarray

I have a local .json file in my iOS App. 
That looks like this:

```
{
  "books": [
  {
        "title": "Book 1",
        "category": ["z","y","w"]
  },
  {
        "title": "Book 2",
        "category": ["x"]
  }
 ]
}
```

I parse it like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"books" ofType:@"json"];
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&errore];

NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

**When I print the dictionary It looks like the 'category' array becomes a string if it contains only one entry**:

```
{
  books = (
   {
      title = "Book 1";
      category = (z,y,w)
   },
   {
     title = "Book 2";
     category = x
   }
 )
}
```

Since I need to loop through all of them how can I just keep the array structure for all of the category items? Even for those with only one entry?

Thanks

**EDIT**: I tested on different mac different xcode5 and is working! I was wondering if has something to do with some sort of setting?

Comment: `"category": ["x"]` would become `category = ( x )` in the dictionary (i.e. an array with a single object). So either your JSON input or your code is different from what you posted.

Comment: @MartinR not really I have that exact structure for it

Comment: Have you tried to replace `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` with `kNilOptions`?

Comment: @luca: I have tried exactly your code with your JSON input, and the result (in condensed form) is `{ books = ( { category =  ( z, y, w ); title = "Book 1"; }, { category = ( x ); title = "Book 2"; } ; }`, so the value of the "category" key is an array.

Comment: @MartinR thats really strange Did you parse the json from a local .json file in the bundle as well?

Comment: @luca: Yes. But how do you print the jsonDic? The NSLog output (or `po jsonDic` in the debugger console) would contain semicolons, which I cannot see in your output.

Comment: @MartinR That is a typo as well I updated my code snippet. I print the dic with a NSLog (%@,jsonDic) and I have no array structure for the single value array!!

Comment: @luca: Typo? What typo? Please **copy/paste** the **real output** into the question. (What you have now still cannot be the real output.)

Comment: @MartinR I'm testing now from a different mac (same exact code just using dropbox) and is working fine here!! does it have something to do with some sort of Xcode5 setting???

Comment: @luca: I don't think so. Are you sure that you copy/pasted the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code and look at `jsonDic`, I get precisely what one would expect:

```
(lldb) po jsonDic
{
    books =     (
                {
            category =             (
                z,
                y,
                w
            );
            title = "Book 1";
        },
                {
            category =             (
                x
            );
            title = "Book 2";
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your print an array like

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"A",@"B"];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

The output will be like

```
2013-11-27 14:49:52.497 TestApp[1629:70b] (
    A,
    B
)
```

So your output given by NSLog when you pass your dictionary is absolutely correct. Thus your `category` key have an array not a string (though it look like a string)